# implementing Some kind of pivot in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table in mysql in this structure

table: member

```
| Id | Name | Lastname | Username 
| --------------------------------
| 1  | Alexi| Lalas    | alexi
| 2  | Jack | Louis    | louis
```

And I have a table called member images with this structre:

table: image

```
| Id | MemberId | Image      | Type  |
|------------------------------------|
| 50 | 1        | face.jpg   |Avetar |
| 51 | 1        | image.jpg  |Gallery|
| 52 | 2        | main.jpg   |Avetar |
| 53 | 2        | jungle.jpg |Gallery|
```

And I want to get this result

```
| Id | Name | Lastname | Username | Image1   | Image2   |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Alexi| Lalas    | alexi    |face.jpg  |image.jpg |
| 2  | Jack | Louis    | louis    |main.jpg  |jungle.jpg|
```

Becuase of some reasons I can't handle is on app side and I have to do it on sql side.
Imagin that I always have 2 type of images and we always have Image1 and Image2.

Any help would be appritiated.

Comment: The keyword you're after is JOIN: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @TasosBitsios No, he wants a pivot, not a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are only two types, you can use the `CASE` expression to do so. Something like this:

```
SELECT
  m.Id,
  m.Name,
  m.LastName, 
  m.UserName,
  MAX(CASE WHEN i.Type = 'Avetar' THEN i.Image END) AS 'Image1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN i.Type ='Gallery' THEN i.Image END) AS 'Image2'
FROM member AS m
LEFT JOIN image AS i ON m.Id = i.MemberId
GROUP BY m.Id,
         m.Name,
         m.LastName, 
         m.UserName;
```

**Note that:** `LEFT JOIN` will include all the members from the `member` table even if they have no images in the `image` table, in this case `NULL` will be returned.

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9efc/1)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is via a subselect (subquery). You would subselect the first column as the image for the user withe Avetar type and the other column subselect would be for the image with the type Gallery. If you can't find a way to make User ID and Type unique in your sub table then you are going to have issues with this type of query. Keep in mind that a subselects can impact performance heavily.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html